# CORS problem on Angular app sending POST to ASP .Net api

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api

i'm trying to write an agular app which will make some http request to an ASP.NET Api.

This is my request from angular (hosted on http://localhost:4200):

```
 httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    })
  };

      let body = {
        "email": this.temail,
        "password": btoa(this.tepassword)
      }

      this.http.post<any>(environment.authUrl, body, this.httpOptions).subscribe(
        (data) => console.log(data),
        (err) => console.log(err)
      )
```

and this my simple method on ASP .Net Api (listening on https://localhost:44317/):

```
        [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage Auth([FromBody] User user)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

i've already installed CORS nuget and used it on config file:

```
       public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        config.EnableCors();
```

i've also installed the Allow CORS: Access-Control-Allow-Origin extension for chrome (
though i use Edge chromium).

Every time i try to send the POST request from angular to ASP i received this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:44317/api/user/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: In the startup file when you configure cors you also need to configure the domains to allow under, take a look here.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1#cors-with-named-policy-and-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution of Sajeetharan doesn't work:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Cors;

namespace ApiAgenda
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*"));

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

i have also write this on the controller:

[EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200/", headers: "*", methods: "*")]

for John Peters, my WebApiConfig.cs is, originally, like this:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace ApiAgenda
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services
            config.EnableCors();

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

i haven't understand how i need to modify it.